# vs code autocompletes not working properly in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views

VS Code doesn't suggest request in `views.py`. I've test pylance, jedi.. all off language server but didn't work.

How can I get a better auto complete in vs code?[image: 1]

Comment: Why would you need an auto complete for a parameter name?

Comment: ohh,Thanks dude
Got it. I thought, I should get  that auto-completion (I'm beginner)